# Show that if $Q_1,Q_2,$... is a an accounting collection of rectangles covering Q, Then$ V(Q) \leq \displaystyle\sum{V(Q_i)} $

Tags: integration

Show that if $Q_1,Q_2,$... is a an accounting collection of rectangles covering Q, Then$ V(Q) \leq \displaystyle\sum{V(Q_i)} $

If I Have an accounting collection of rectangles covering Q , I can say that collection can be finite or enumerable. For the finite case 
We cosntruct a partition p de ' using the end of the components.
Then each one of rectangles are the are the union of sub-rectangles determined for p.

Then  V(Q)=$\displaystyle\sum_{R\subseteq Q}V(R)$
Now , each subrectangles R determined fo p that is content in Q,also it is content in at least one $Q_i$

Then $\displaystyle\sum_{R\subseteq Q}V(R)$ $\leq$ $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{k}$  [$\displaystyle\sum_{R\subseteq Q_i}V(R)$]

By a theorem $V(Q_i)$=$\displaystyle\sum_{R\subseteq Q_i}V(R)$

so
$ V(Q) \leq \displaystyle\sum{V(Q_i)} $

Now I don't know like to do the second case , when is an enumerable collection
 I am not sure if I have to show when collection is enumrable or consider when collection is infinite.

Comment: What do you mean by accounting? Countable, perhaps?

Comment: in the infinite case, even in dimension $1$ it may not be straightforward